# Error with client in mocha when I use grunt

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, mocha.js, end-to-end, nightwatch.js

I'm new to E2E test and Grunt. I'm working on end to end test using Nightwatch.js, PahantomJS, and Mocha.

Without grunt, the test is passed, but with grunt I get an error with "client".

**Without grunt :**

1. Launch Selenium sever

   `$ selenium-server -p 4444 -role hub`
2. Register Ghost Driver to Selenium Hub

   `$ node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444`
3. Execute nightwatch

   `$ node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch -c bin/nightwatch.json -t tests/test.js`

and then the test is passed.

**With grunt :**

I get this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` with client.

The result of `console.log(client);` is

```
function (err){
    if (err instanceof Error || toString.call(err) === "[object Error]") return done(err);
    if (null != err) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(err) === '[object Object]') {
        return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err)));
      } else {
        return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + err));
      }
    }
    done();
  }
```

My codes are like following scripts.

- test.js

  ```
  describe("sample test", function() {

      it("should say no item", function(client) {

          console.log("client:", client);

          client
              .url("http://sample.com/")
              .waitForElementVisible("body", 10000)
              .click("a.link1")
              .waitForElementVisible(".article", 10000)
              .expect.element("div.cart").text.to.contain("no item");
      }); 
  });
  ```
- Gruntfile.js

  ```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {

      var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

      nightwatch.initGrunt(grunt);

      grunt.initConfig({

          nightwatch: {
              options: {
                cwd: "./"
              },
              "default" : {},
              browserstack: {
                  argv: {
                      env: "browserstack"
                  },
                  settings: {
                      silent: true
                  }
              },
              "all" : {
                  argv: {
                      env: "default, browserstack"
                  }
              }
          },

          mochacli: {
              options: {
                  colors: true,
                  "check-leaks": false,
                  ui: "bdd",
                  reporter: "spec",
                  timeout: 20000
              },
              e2e: ["tests/*.js"]
          }

      });

      require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt);

      grunt.registerTask("nightwatch", [
          "selenium_phantom_hub",
          "mochacli:e2e",
          "selenium_stop"
      ]);

      grunt.registerTask("default", ["nightwatch"]);

  };
  ```
- package.json

  ```
  {
      "name": "Nightwatch-sample",
      "description": "test using Nightwatch.js",
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
          "phantomjs": "^1.9.8",
          "nightwatch": "^0.8.4",
          "chai-nightwatch": "~0.1.x",
          "mocha-nightwatch": "2.2.6"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
          "chai": "^3.2.0",
          "chai-nightwatch": "^0.1.1",
          "grunt": "~0.4.4",
          "grunt-mocha-cli": "^1.14.0",
          "grunt-selenium-webdriver": "^0.2.451",
          "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.3.0"
      }
  }
  ```
- nightwatch.json

  ```
  {
      "src_folders" : ["tests"],
      "output_folder" : "reports",
      "custom_commands_path" : "",
      "custom_assertions_path" : "",
      "page_objects_path" : "",
      "globals_path" : "",

      "selenium" : {
          "start_process" : false,
          "server_path" : "",
          "log_path" : "",
          "host" : "127.0.0.1",
          "port" : 4444,
          "cli_args" : {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
            "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
          }
      },

      "test_settings" : {
          "default" : {
              "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
              "selenium_port"  : 4444,
              "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
              "silent": true,
              "firefox_profile": false,
              "chrome_driver" : "",
              "screenshots" : {
                  "enabled" : true,
                  "path" : "tests/screenshots",
                  "on_failure": true
              },
              "test_runner": "mocha",
              "desiredCapabilities": {
                  "browserName": "phantomjs",
                  "javascriptEnabled": true,
                  "acceptSslCerts": true,
                  "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Your issue seems to be with grunt setup.  `it("should say no item", function(client) {` this looks wrong to me, as nothing is passing the client to your test.  `it` is a standard mocha function, how would it know about the client?

Answer (score 0):

@Filype already mentioned in a comment why your code is not working as you want.

To elaborate a bit: The place where you use 'client' as function parameter is used by mocha to pass in a 'done' function that you can use to signal mocha your test is done in an async situation - that is why console.log(client) is printing what it is. You've probably ended up with this code because nightwatch has a structure that provides the client like this.

So to get it running you should rename the parameter 'client' to 'done', and call done() when the test is done. You also should instantiate client yourself somehow.

However: I do think that nightwatch and mocha are not a really good fit together since they provide similar functionalities that cannot be merged nicely. Maybe you should just run nightwatch from grunt without trying to add mocha? Google says it can be done :-) https://github.com/gextech/grunt-nightwatch

Mocha is flexible enough to do a lot of things if you really want it to, but I'd say running another test runner like system inside mocha is stretching it.

UPDATE: Apparently Nightwatch has recently added some Mocha support https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/501 I don't know at what level. I would still think you are better off running it standalone if you aren't using mocha already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to do testing without mocha. Now I can do end to end testing successfully.